# SignalR: How can I make Windows Service notify my MVC application whenever it write records into the database?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, signalr

I have a windows service which writes data to a database table (database is IBM informix if relevant). I want to signal my MVC application whenever the windows service has inserted new records into the database. Can this be done using SignalR? If yes, how? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why dont you using your MVC to write data into DB instead? that way, it would be lot easier

Comment: @Mark I wish I could. But that is out of question. There has been Windows Service already in place since a couple of years.